# Add field to existing JSON object with sprayJSON (scala)

Tags: json, scala, spray

I made a case class to store some of my data. The case class looks like the following:

```
case class Job(id: Option[Int], title: String, description: Option[String],
              start: Date, end: Option[Date], customerId: Int)
```

I was using the following formatter to write/read my JSON objects:

```
implicit val jobFormat = jsonFormat6(Job.apply)
```

I've got some problems with the write/read because I need to add a field to the JSON (**but not to the case class**), for example: "test": "test". I tried to write a custom read/write with the following code:

```
implicit object jobFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Job] {
  override def read(json: JsValue): JobRow = ???

  override def write(job: Job): JsValue = ??
}
```

I couldn't get the working code, could somebody help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more context? Do you want the "test" property to be ignored when the JSON is unmarshalled to the case class? IIRC extra properties are ignored by default. Or do you need some way to access the property when it is unmarshalled?

Comment: Well the case class has 6 elements in it, but I want to add a seventh element in the JSON without adding it to the case class. 

My question is: is this possible without writing the whole write/read?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What `jsonFormat6` does is to create you autogenerated `RootJsonFormat[Job]` object. You can create your custom instances with extending `RootJsonFormat[Job]`. In this case, you need to create custom instance that decorates autogenerated one and adds logic on write method.

The code will look like this:

```
implicit object JobFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Job] {
  // to use autogenerated jobFormat
  val jobFormat = jsonFormat6(Job.apply)

  // leave read at it is
  override def read(json: JsValue): JobRow =
    jobFormat.read(json)

  // Change write to add your custom logic
  override def write(job: Job): JsValue = {
    val json = jobFormat.write(job).asJsonObject
    JsObject(json.fields + ("test" -> JsString("test")))
  }
}
```

*PS: I haven't compiled code, however, overall implementation will look like this.*